# Show that, for all $x>0: \frac{1}{x+1/2} \leq \ln(1+1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I was able to prove that $\ln(1+1/x) \leq 1/x$ by integrating both sides and taking the upper boundaries of the integral area. However, that does not seen to work for the inequation in question.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=\ln (1+1/x)-\frac{1}{x+1/2}$, and prove that it is positive whenever $x$ is positive.

Comment: It probably helps to use $\ln (1+1/x) = \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $t \mapsto 1/t$ is convex for $t \geq 1$. Therefore it lies above any of its tangent lines on this interval. Use this to get a lower bound for $\log(1+x)$ for any $x\geq 0$:

$$\log(1+x) = \int_1^{1+x} \frac{\mathrm dt}{t} \geq \int_1^{1+x} \ell(t) \mathrm dt$$

where $t \mapsto \ell(t)$ is the tangent line of $t \mapsto 1/t$ at $t = 1+x/2$. This results in $$\log(1+x) \geq \frac{2x}{x+2}$$ for any $x\geq 0$. Now replace $x$ by $1/x$.